# mapping does not work for one entity in EF code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, mapping

I'm using `EF 6.1.1` code first with `.NET framework 4`, I have an abstract base class `BaseEntity` that all other of my entities inherited from that. I have following classes in my model:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ....
}

public class Document:BaseEntity

public class OrderHeader:Document

public class RequestHeader:Document
```

I want to change the EF default convention mappings by defining following mapping files:

```
public class RequestHeader_Mapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<RequestHeader>
{
    public RequestHeader_Mapping()
    {                   
        this.ToTable("RequestHeader");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("DocumentId");
        ...
    }
}

public class OrderHeader_Mapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<OrderHeader>
{
    public OrderHeader_Mapping()
    {                   
        this.ToTable("OrderHeader");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("DocumentId");
        ...
    }
}
```

**[Updated]**

```
public partial class Document_Mapping : BaseEntity_Mapping<Document>
{
    public Document_Mapping()
    {                   
        this.ToTable("Document");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.HasOptional(t => t.Creater).WithMany().HasForeignKey(d => d.CreatedById);
        this.HasOptional(t => t.Modifier).WithMany().HasForeignKey(d => d.ModifiedById);
        this.HasOptional(t => t.Owner).WithMany().HasForeignKey(d => d.OwnerId);
        this.HasOptional(t => t.DocumentStatu).WithMany().HasForeignKey(d => d.DocumentStatusId);
        this.HasOptional(t => t.DocumentStation).WithMany(t => t.Documents).HasForeignKey(d => d.DocumentStationId);
        this.HasOptional(t => t.DocumentType).WithMany().HasForeignKey(d => d.DocumentTypeId);
        this.HasOptional(t => t.DocumentFolder).WithMany().HasForeignKey(d => d.MainFolderId);
        this.HasOptional(t => t.SecurityLevel).WithMany).HasForeignKey(d => d.SecurityLevelId);

        this.Ignore(t => t.ToDocuments);
    }
}


public partial class BaseEntity_Mapping<TEntity> : EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> where TEntity:BaseEntity
{
    public BaseEntity_Mapping()
    {
        this.HasKey(e => e.Id);
         this.Property(t=>t.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.Ignore(t => t.MustDelete);
        this.Ignore(t=>t.PreviousState);
        this.Ignore(t => t.State);
    }
}
```

and use them in following way in my DbContext:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
     modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
     modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
     modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RequestHeader_Mapping());
     modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OrderHeader_Mapping());
     modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Document_Mapping());
 }
```

It works for `RequestHeader`, but does not for `OrderHeader`, I mean that generated key for `RequestHeader` table is `DocumentId`, but for `OrderHeader` is `Id` yet, I have been really confused, does know anyone where is the problem?

Comment: it also works for OrderHeader, both OrderHeader and RequestHeader have DocumentId column as PK, check this [image](http://s17.postimg.org/4cj1757r3/Image.png)

Comment: Any reason why `Id` property in `BaseEntity` is virtual?

Comment: @YuliamChandra: I know, it should be as you said, but it doesn't work for me!(I summarized `OrderHeader` and `RequestHeader` classes, they have other properties and relations, too)

Comment: @DavidG: I updated the question, `Id` isn't `virtual`.

Comment: @Masoud Do you want `BaseEntity.Id` to always be the primary key? If so, it's worth putting `[Key]` attribute on it.

Comment: Do you have a DbSet<Document> or `DbSet<RequestHeader>` and `DbSet<OrderHeader>` or is there any Navigation Property of type Document in your model?

Comment: @DavidG, No you dont have to explicitly add Key attribute, EF by its convention can determine which column to be the PK

Comment: @codeworx: I have a `DbSet<Document>` in my `DbContext`, yeah I have navigation property of type `Document` in my model(this navigation property does not belongs to `OrderHeader` or `RequestHeader`), I have some navigation property with `OrderHeader` and `RequestHeader` type too.

Comment: Do you have an `EntityTypeConfiguration<Document>` too?

Comment: @codeworx: yes, I have.

Comment: @Masoud Sorry for being unclear... could you please post the Document mapping ;-)

Comment: This can not be reproduced with the code you provided. I've built a little test app with your code and it works as expected. You can check by yourself if you want: [download](http://1drv.ms/1ro4Jss)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `OrderHeader` had a one-to-zero or one relation with another entity, when I remove it the problem solved!